# How do you set a vid field with block item value in rebol/red?

Tags: rebol, red

That works:

```
 test: "test"
 view [field test]
```

That doesn't:

```
 test: ["test1" "test2"]
 view [field test/1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Red, paths are not directly accepted by VID, but they can be provided after some keywords like `data`, which can be used in your case to indicate the value of the `field` widget:

```
view [field data test/1]
```

An alternative way is to build the VID block dynamically, the simplest way here would be to use `compose`:

```
view compose [field (test/1)]
```